# What does <h:messages> do in JSF?

Tags: jsf, message

I am learning JSF and came across this line:

```
<h:messages layout="table"></h:messages>
```

in a sample application ?

Am not sure what does this line do? I get no error when removing the line from the code, and am able to run it and get the same output ?

Comment: The line I came accross in the sample code:  <h:messages layout="table"></h:messages>

Comment: I've edited your question. Use the Ctrl+K shortcut to write code in a question / answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `h:messages` tag renders all messages for the current JSF view which are not covered by a `h:message` (remark the missing 's' at the end) tag. Messages can be generated explicitly by your backing beans (`FacesContext.addMessage`) or implicitly by JSF.

E.g. if you have marked an input value as required and the user submits the form without filling in the required value, an error message will be added to the view. If a `h:message` tag is bound to the relevant component, the message will be rendered there, otherwise it will be rendered by the global `h:messages` tag in your view (if any).

The `layout` attribute specifies what the HTML code to be generated should look like. The `table` layout (used in your example) uses an HTML table to display messages, while the `list` layout uses a bulleted list (HTML `ul` tag).

If you do *not* specify a `h:messages` tag in your view and also no `h:message` tags, the user will not be informed about errors. Therefore, it is best practice to include a `h:message` tag for each input component of your view and a `h:messages` tag for your whole view to ensure that all messages are visible to the user.

You will find a compact JSF tag reference at [JSF Toolbox](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/index.jsf).

Comment: Concerning "renders all messages for the current JSF view which are not covered". I don't think that is completely correct. It will show all messages except when you specify globalOnly="true".

Answer (score 5):

The components `<h:message>` and `<h:messages>` are dedicated to display messages to users (generally error message).

For example, when you have a validation on a field that failed (for example the user didn't fill a required field, or inputed a string in a number-only field), then a `FacesMessage` is added to the `FacesContext` object. The `<h:message>` and `<h:messages>` are then used to display the message in the page.

The component `<h:messages>` will display all the messages contained in the `FacesContext`, while the `<h:message>` is dedicated to a specific clientId (a specific field). The latter is usefull when you want to place the message close to a field for example.

Note that you can add any kind of message that will displayed to the user:

```
FacesContext.getInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("The message to display"));
```

In this example, the first parameter is the ID field of the field that is concerned by this message (usefull when the message is a validation message for a specific field). `null` means that the message is a general information (i.e. not linked to any particular field).

You can see an example of this component [here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/messages.jsf). Note that this example uses the `rich:messages` that is an extension (provided by RichFaces) of the "basic" `<h:message/>`, but the principle is the same.