# Several messages programmatically in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, message

I've got two places to put messages in my website. Messages related with an aside div and messages related with the main container.

I'm using this two h:messages simultaneusly within the same page (it's forms have prependId=false and no id so messages ids are not appended with others):

```
<h:messages id="container-messages" infoClass="info-message" warnClass="warn-message" errorClass="error-message" globalOnly="false" />

<h:messages id="aside-messages" infoClass="info-message" warnClass="warn-message" errorClass="error-message" globalOnly="false" />
```

Then inside my Java code I'm using this to print some messages:

```
facesContext.addMessage("container-messages", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "one message", null));
```

The first problem is that this works, but it prints the message in both  and not only in the container-messages.

Later I replaced  with :

```
<h:message id="container-messages" infoClass="info-message" warnClass="warn-message" errorClass="error-message"/>

<h:message id="aside-messages" infoClass="info-message" warnClass="warn-message" errorClass="error-message" />
```

and tried also:

```
<h:message for="container-messages" infoClass="info-message" warnClass="warn-message" errorClass="error-message"/>

<h:message for="aside-messages" infoClass="info-message" warnClass="warn-message" errorClass="error-message" />
```

but in both cases it doesn't show anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `h:messages` is for so-called **global** messages which are unrelated to a specific component and therefore the `for` attribute is not allowed here.

The `h:message` is for messages related to a specific component, therefore the `for` attribute is required, this means you **need** a component to bind to.

To reach your goal you can use two `h:message` elements bound to some component (e.g. an empty `h:grapicImage`) in the following way:

```
    <h:graphicImage id="someID" />
    <h:message for="someID" id="container-messages" infoClass="info-message" 
         warnClass="warn-message" errorClass="error-message"/>
    <div>
         stuff
    </div>
    <h:message for="someID" id="aside-messages" infoClass="info-message" 
         warnClass="warn-message" errorClass="error-message" />
```

Adding the messages in the way you already described:

```
    facesContext.addMessage("container-messages", new 
         FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "message1", null));
    facesContext.addMessage("aside-messages", new 
         FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "message2", null));
```

**See also:**

- [What does h:messages do in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491416/what-does-hmessages-do-in-jsf)
- [jsf h:messages/ h:message for specific clientId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457063/jsf-hmessages-hmessage-for-specific-clientid)

Comment: thank you, but I still don't understand what's the purpose of <h:messages globalOnly="false" /> if I can't bound them to specific clientId messages.

Comment: If you set `globalOnly="false"` it means that it will display the messages you added for a specific component (e.g. "container-messages") if for that component no `h:message` is defined.